# Tableview inner Scrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am starting to develop for iOS. I'm having a difficulty for days, is as follows:

My `UIViewController` has a `UIScrollView`, and within that `UIScrollView` i have other controls in the following order:

- `ImageView`
- `ImageView`
- `TableView`
- `Label`
- `TextView`

The lines of my `UITableView` may vary. 
I need the size of my `UITableView` displays all rows that contains at entatanto I want to scroll the `UITableView` get caught, and that only works scrolls the `UIScrollView`.

Have deactivated the `UIScrollView` my `UITableView` but the table view does not display all rows.

Comment: Can u share the chunk of the project or part of the code?

Comment: Can you post some code, whatever you tried so far and can you rephrase your question a little bit so that it clearly explains your expected output?

Comment: Sorry friends as I am new forum i can't post pictures. But I'm willing to attempt makes it clearer my question.

Comment: I summarized what I want is that the tableview show all their lines.

I disabled the "Scrolling Enabled" because I want the scrollView scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var frame = tableView.frame
    var oldHeight = frame.height
    frame.size.height = cells*cellHeight //cells should be assigned to the number
                                         //of cells you have, and cell height to
                                         //the height of each, usually 44 pts
    tableView.frame = frame
    var scrollFrame = scrollView.contentSize
    scrollFrame.height = scrollFrame.height - oldHeight + tableView.frame.height
    scrollView.contentSize = scrollFrame
```

Sometimes, .contentSize will not work if auto layout is enabled, it depends on how/where you use it.

Otherwise, tableView should be assigned to your table, scrollView to your scrollView, and cells/cell height as stated above.

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks for your help. 

Please let me know where should I put your code. In the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: You should put it after you load the content of your tableView.  If that is in the viewDidLoad method, that should work.

Comment: Friend Trumpeter201 put more details in answer below 

Thanks!

Comment: Dear friend, I am not getting. Could you give me more details about implementation?

Comment: Put it in your viewDidLoad method.